# Authenticating and Authorizing using ADFS WS-Fed protocol

Tags: authentication, authorization, asp.net-web-api2, jwt, adfs3.0

I am working on implementing Authenticating and Authorization in my application.

**For Authentication:**
I configured by ADFS Server with WS-Fed Sign in Protocol and enabled JWT. Created MVC application and configured to use WS-Fed for authenticating user.

Now question here is how do I store JWT token in my cookie after successfully login?

Here is my code

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        private static string realm = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Wtrealm"];
        private static string adfsMetadata = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ADFSMetadata"];

        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions{ CookieName="JwtToken",CookieHttpOnly=false});
            app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
                new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    Wtrealm = realm,
                    MetadataAddress = adfsMetadata
                });
        }
    }
```

**For Authorization**
I have a separate Web API project. I want to authorize my api's by passing the JWT token in header of every request but not sure how to extract JWT token from cookie and pass it to web api for validating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here http://www.software-architects.com/devblog/2015/02/02/ADFS-and-ADAL-Lab.

ADAL (Active Directory Authentication Libraryfor .NET and for JavaScript) which can be used to acquire token in mvc application and pass the token in header for authorizing web api.